# MIPS QtSpim Data Movement Issue

Tags: assembly, mips, qtspim

I am having an issue with a program I am writing right now, here is the program exactly.

```
.data
BYTE1:  .byte 0xAD
BYTE2:  .byte 0xDE

WORD1:  .word 0
WORD2:  .word 0
WORD3:  .word 0
WORD4:  .word 0
WORD5:  .word 0

MYNAME: .asciiz "SamW"

    .text
    .globl main

main:

#WORD1
lui $t0, 0xCAFE
srl $t0, $t0, 16
la $t1, WORD1
sw $t0, 0($t1)

#WORD2
lui $t0, 0xBEAD
srl $t0, $t0, 16
la $t1, WORD2
sw $t0, 0($t1)

#WORD3
lui $t0, 0xDEAF
srl $t0, $t0, 16
la $t1, WORD3
sw $t0, 0($t1)

#WORD4
lui $t0, 0xDEED
srl $t0, $t0, 16
la $t1, WORD4
sw $t0, 0($t1)

#MYNAME
lw $t0, 8($t1)
la $t1, WORD5
sw $t0, 0($t1)

#LOAD_B1
la $t0, BYTE1
lbu $s0, 0($t0)

#LOAD_B2
addi, $t0, $t0, 1
lbu $s1, 0($t0)

#LOAD_W1
la $t0, WORD1
lw $s2, 0($t0)

addi $t0, $t0, 4


#LOAD_W2

lw $s3, 0($t0)
```

The issue that is occurring is with the last couple lines of code where I am instructing a lw to pull the information from WORD1 and WORD2 and store it in a save register.  For some reason when I go to run that code one time through nothing happens, but then when I clear out all of the registers and reinitialize the program again, within the first 2 instructions those instructions are executed correctly.  Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Notice the highlighted instruction and what is printed in Register 19.  Once again on the initial run through the code nothing happened in Register 19 then when I reinitialized it that popped in on instruction 3.

Here is a picture of the memory banks:

[image]

Comment: Here is a picture of the memory banks

http://i63.tinypic.com/wobyw.png

Comment: Works for me in PCSpim. Note that you should explicitly end your program with a syscall 10.

Comment: Two `.byte` directives at the start of your `.data` section probably misalign all the words.  Surprised this doesn't fault.